# Very basic confusion about probability and Bayes theorem

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, bayes-theorem

I have this (very trivial but very insidious) doubt about probability. Suppose I have two categories A and B, whose individuals can have two properties, P and Q. Consider the following table:

```
  A  B
P 2  5
Q 12 15
```

This table tells us, for example, that 2 individuals in A have property P. Now the question is: what is the probability that an individual from group A has property P?

My doubt is: do I have to use a Bayes theorem

$Pr(P|A) = \frac{Pr(A|P)Pr(P)}{Pr(A)}$

or the basic definition of probability

$P(P|A) = \frac{2}{2+12}$

Thank you for helping.

Comment: The result is right: $P(P|A)=\frac2{14}$. But you used the frequencies $n(X)$ rather than the probabilities, which is right as well.

Comment: Did you work it out both ways? If you write out the fractions you use in the Bayes rule approach you'll see the proof of Bayes Theorem unfold in front of your eyes.

Comment: The second probability is only true if $P$ and $Q$ are disjoint and complete. In other words, if every individual is either $P$ or $Q,$ but not both.

Comment: Bayes' theorem is overkill. Basic probability is fine and shows an understanding of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either is fine. Note that Bayes' Theorem would give
$$\frac{\frac 2 7 \cdot \frac{7}{34}}{\frac {14}{34}} = \frac{2}{14}$$
just like your other answer. (Personally, I think your second solution is much simpler, but it should be comforting that the two methods agree.)

Comment: My mistake, I corrected the question with $Pr(P|A)$

Answer (score 1):

The result is right: $P(P|A)=\frac2{14}$. But you used the frequencies $n(X)$ rather than the probabilities, which is right as well.

The Bayes theorem with frequencies is

$$Pr(P|A)=\frac{n(A|P)\cdot n(P)}{n(A)}=\frac{n(P\cap A)}{n(A)}=\frac{n(P\cap A)}{n(P \cap A)+n(Q \cap A)}=\frac{2}{2+12}$$

with your contingency table

\begin{array}{c|c|c}  & A&B&\sum \\ \hline P & n(P \cap A)&n(P \cap B)& n(P)\\ \hline Q&n(Q \cap A)&n(Q \cap B)&n(Q) \\ \hline \sum&n(A) &n(B)& N\\  \end{array}

$n(X)$ are the frequencies of event $X$ and $N$ is the total number of frequencies.